# Why can't I find my OnePlus bullets wireless Z headphones? Bluetooth seems working and finds other devices

Tags: networking, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I bought a pair of Bluetooth headphones (OnePlus bullets wireless Z bass edition) but I can't pair them with my pc because I can't find the device or connect it with its MAC address. It doesn't seem to be a PC problem because I can connect my phone (a OnePlus 7T) without problems. I tried connecting the headphones to the smartphone and no problems occurred. I can't really understand where is the problem... somebody can help me?

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue with my oneplus bullet bass edition.I was able to find the solution.

Steps:-

1. Factory reset your OnePlus earphones by pressing <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys for 3 seconds.
2. On your terminal enter `$bluetoothctl`
3. Enter `$scan on`
4. Your OnePlus bullet will be in the list.
5. Download bluetooth manager 'blueman' `$apt get install blueman`
6. Setup your device using blueman and make it connect from the list.